# Can't get AngularJS decorator for TextAngular to work

Tags: angularjs, decorator

I'm not sure I totally understand *decorators* in AngularJS - I'm trying to modify TextAngular as in this example: https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Setting-Defaults

My code:

```
angular.module('MyAngularApp', ['cfp.hotkeys', 'omr.angularFileDnD', 'textAngular']);

angular.module('MyAngularApp', ['textAngular']).config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    // changing the classes of the icons
    $provide.decorator('taTools', ['$delegate', function (taTools) {
        taTools.bold.iconclass = 'icon icon-button';
        return taTools;
    }]);
}]);
```

With this decorator active, I just get a blank web page, no error messages.

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all, to retrieve an existing angular module, you need to just give it the name, not a second param of an array.

Answer (score 1):

@JoelJeske comment is correct - just get your module, don't redeclare it.

```
angular.module('MyAngularApp', ['cfp.hotkeys', 'omr.angularFileDnD', 'textAngular']);

angular.module('MyAngularApp').config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    // changing the classes of the icons
    $provide.decorator('taTools', ['$delegate', function (taTools) {
        taTools.bold.iconclass = 'icon icon-button';
        return taTools;
    }]);
}]);
```